# AWS - MySQL - keep getting lost connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-rds

I have tried to resolve this issue for couple days, but nothing has worked out. I have a Node server mySQL on RDS, but I keep getting disconnection over night, and server got shutdown.

I tried to add a function that handle disconnection (from google/stackoverflow), but it didnt seem to fix the problem

```
function handleDisconnect() {
  // create new connection
  db = mysql.createConnection(dbIdentity); 
  // re-connect to mySQL and handle err if cant connect
  db.connect(function(err) {              
    if(err) {                                     
      console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
      setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); // repeat the process
    }                                     
  });                                     

  connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('db error', err);
    if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { 
      handleDisconnect();                         
    } else {                                      
    throw err;                                  
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: have you tried changing the default timeout? It's probably set to 8 hours now, the mysql default.

Comment: I just changed it, will see how that goes. Thank you